# How to remove url properties in SAP Commerce / Hybris?

Tags: java, tomcat, sap-commerce-cloud

Our SAP Commerce / Hybris shop has the following url properties at the product detail page:
`?siteUid=test&siteName=test-Onlineshop&metaRobots=index%2Cfollow&multiDimensionalProduct=true`

Is it possible to hide them, without breaking the shop?

Answer (score 0):

I think Hybris OOTB doesn't have mentioned query parameters included in the product URL, so I don't know how it's been used in your project and how you form the URL. But yes, you can get rid of it if you know its use cases.

say, If you are using these attributes on the storefront to render the data/page, you can send these attributes as a model attributes or part of a product data object.

e.g.
`model.addAttribute("multiDimensionalProduct", TRUE);`
You can add those attributes in ProductPageController or before view controller or anywhere in the filter chain where it's available. you can get its value using `${multiDimensionalProduct}`

If you have any use case for serverside, you can store/get attributes from a session. For instance, in your given URL you can easily get siteUid & SiteName from the session site (cmsSite) object.

Comment: In the meantime I noticed that if I click on a product on a category page, about 95% of all products get the additonal attributes. But I can remove them and everything works still fine. But it gets appendet just on the redirection to the product. Do you have an idea where would be the best place to look for to remove them from appending?

Comment: `DefaultProductModelUrlResolver` is responsible to resolve product URL, now you can debug this when you trying to open the category page and see how your URL forms.

Comment: if this helps, you can upvote and mark this post as answered

Comment: I didn't look at it in a while, but next week it's the next topic on my to do list :)